# How do you work with a single ORM query result in FuelPHP?

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I have a query that is returning a single result and I'm wondering if there's a way to access the properties of that result without having to loop through it since I am limiting it to a single result.

Here is my query:

```
$user = Model_User::find()
    ->where('email_address', Input::post('email_address'))
    ->where('password', Input::post('password'))
    ->limit(1);
```

The only way I've found to access the results is to run the `get()` method on `$user` and loop through the result, but I figured I was missing something and that there was an easier way to return `$user` as a single object that I can work with since I am limiting it to a single result.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try

`$user->get_one()`?

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
$user = Model_User::find_by_email_address_and_password(Input::post('email_address'), Input::post('password'));
```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Uku Loskit ask you the right syntax.
If you want to retrieve always a single result, you can merge the code:

```
$user = Model_User::find()
    ->where('email_address', Input::post('email_address'))
    ->where('password', Input::post('password'))
    ->get_one();
```

An advice for you: be careful using directly Input::post('var_name'), it would be better to use a validation before saving variables.
Another way is to set the framework to perfrom some action, like htmlentities(), for every $_GET and $_POST variable.